# Query SQLite Database on External Storage with Android App

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I need to write an Android app that can query a SQLite database that is stored on a device's external storage, but I cannot figure out how despite everything I have looked at online, most of which was on StackOverflow. Here's the constructor for the class that I want to use to work with the database. I believe that this piece of code is sufficient information for my question, but if it is not, I can provide more.

```
public KetaiSQLite(PApplet p, String dbName, int dbVersion, String dataRootDir)
{
    this.context = p.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    DATABASE_NAME = dbName;
    DATABASE_VERSION = dbVersion;
    DATA_ROOT_DIRECTORY = dataRootDir;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context, dbName);
    this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

How can I modify this so that I can query from a database on external storage? At the moment, `db.getPath()` returns `/data/data/processing.test.app/databases/appData.sqlite`.

Comment: don't look online sites like `StackOverflow`, just look offline documentation for **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase**

Comment: @pskink I looked through some of the documentation already and did not understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` handles database creation and version management.

But you don't want that, so just use the [openDatabase() function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) directly.

Comment: I assume that the location of the database is passed to the function?

Comment: You don't need to assume; you can just read the documentation.

Comment: Or that. I am sorry. I did not sleep well last night.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After weeks of trying to do this in various ways (I am using Processing, so things are a little different than they are when writing a normal Android app), this answer got my app working! Writing a library for Processing to interact with the database in the manner you described for me seems to have solved the problem.